# FBAR _ FinCen reporting - reporting of girlfriend

Tags: united-states, bank-account, fbar

I have a foreign bank account and my girlfriend (she is NOT a US citizen) is a joint on the account.  Do I need to report her as a joint account holder?

I have only the one account with her, but she has her personal accounts (I am not joint on her accounts).  Do I have to report her personal accounts?

Comment: To be clear: gf is not US citizen **OR resident**?

Answer (score 2):

You need to report **your** accounts, not other persons. However, if you have a joint account with another person - it is **your** account, jointly. So the joint account has to be reported, your girlfriend's personal accounts - not (unless the money there is yours or you have signature authority, of course). For a joint account - you need to report who are the joint holders, yes.